# Convertir a array type el objeto devuelto por las function scan de aws dynamo

Tags: javascript, aws, dynamodb

Hola estoy probando consumir una tabla de aws dymanodb y veo que me esta devolviendo un objecto en el response, y necesito convertir los Items a array para iterar:

```
   const params = {
     TableName: "xxxxx",
    //ProjectionExpression: "name1, name2",
   };

   const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

   docClient.scan(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
         console.log("xxxx::fetchData::error-" + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
      } else {
         console.log("la respuesta ", data)
      }
   });
```

Salida de la consola:

> la respuesta xxxx::fetchData::success-[object Object]

Answer (score 0):

Según veo en la documentación:

[DocumentClient](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#scan-property)

El objeto que retornar tiene (entre varias otras) la propiedad Items:

> Items — (Array<map>) — a serializable JavaScript object. For information about the supported types see the DynamoDB Data Model

Que es un array por lo que en teoría deberías poder hacer:

```
data.Items.forEach(item => console.log(item));
```

O intentar en todo caso pasarlo a un array con Array.from() que recibe un iterable:

Array.from(data.Items);

[Array from](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)